# How to show that $\int_0^{x^2} \frac{\arctan(t)}{t+1}dt$ is bounded?

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{x^2} \frac{\arctan(t)}{t+1}dt$$

I can show that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t+1}=0$

and $\lim_{t\to\infty}(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t+1})=0$

I know that is not enough, so what more do I need?

Comment: I mean, What's happening at $+\infty$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is false. As $t\to\infty$, $\arctan t\to\pi/2$, and so the integral is asymptotic to the divergent integral $\frac{\pi}2 \int_N^{x^2} \frac{dt}{t+1} = \frac{\pi}2 \ln\big(\frac {x^2+1}{N+1}\big)\underset{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty$. (Whether we have $x$ or $x^2$ as the upper limit is irrelevant.)

Comment: That was helpful

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(t)}{t+1}\; dt$ diverges by the Comparison test, e.g. comparing to $1/t$.